# how to query 10 items at a time from Parse?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I'm making an app on Android, using Parse as the backend, hosted by AWS. I'm querying this table that have a list of images. In order not have the app wait a long time while querying in the back ground. I would like to query 10 images at a time, and once I've scrolled to the bottom of the RecyclerView, I will query the next 10.

So I know you can limit the amount of query by query.limit(10), thereby setting the callback to only give 10 results. And I can also set the results to be ordered according to the time it was uploaded. But when I re-query the next 10 sets of results, how do I make sure that none of the results are duplicates of the previous 10? Does Parse have any inbuilt methods that deal with this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: please let me know if it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889157/how-to-implement-infinite-scroll-with-recyclerview-in-android-using-parse

Comment: Yes this works! I wasn't aware that there was a setskip function.